# Show number of answers as tooltip in the sidebar questions

Tags: feature-request, related-questions, linked-questions, sidebar

I don't know it is good idea or not but as an user when I go to some question and couldn't find good answer there I tend to look into the sidebar questions. It shows me number of upvotes for each questions, but doesn't say number of answers it has. So if I want to know if that question is resolved or at least answered I have to click and go into each of them.

[image]

I think it's good if I can see number of answers for each question rather than their upvotes, and decide whether to go to that question or not. I am more interested in seeing answers than knowing how many upvotes each questions got (in sidebar questions). Or may be display both of them if feasible?

What are your thoughts?

**Updated Request**: Show number of answers as tooltip in addition to the number of votes in sidebar questions. (Thanks @ShadowWizard)

Comment: Why not have both?

Comment: It adds some mystery without the number of answers. Ooooo, SPOOKY!

Comment: @SabreTooth because it would be too cluttered, there's not enough room for both. Maybe as tooltip.

Comment: 3 downvotes LOL.. Seems like asking for something is big offense here!

Comment: @SabreTooth yep I asked if it's feasible somehow then display both.

Comment: @ShadowWizard makes sense. It doesn't show anything now hovering over sidebar questions, tooltip can be helpful.

Comment: @Kalpesh downvotes on meta often mean disagreement - probably people disagreeing with your suggestion.

Comment: @Kalpesh right, you can change the request to ask to show number of answers as tooltip in addition to the number of votes, not instead.

Comment: thanks @ShadowWizard i just updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd love to see this feature implemented - a high vote count doesn't necessarily mean you'll find something useful there!

Till then, here's a userscript to show the number of answers to a linked or related question:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Show answer count for questions in the sidebar
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A
// @version      1.0
// @description  Shows the answer count for related or linked questions as a tooltip (in the sidebar)
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
$('.sidebar-linked .linked .spacer a, .sidebar-related .related .spacer a').each(function(i) {
    if (!i % 2 == 0) { //odd only (ie. question title)
        var id = $(this).attr('href').split('/')[2],
            sitename = $(location).attr('hostname').split('.')[0],
            that = $(this);

        $.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + id + "?order=desc&sort=activity&site=" + sitename, function(json) {
            answers = json.items[0].answer_count;
            that.attr('title', answers + (answers == 1 ? ' answer' : ' answers'));
        });
    }
});
```

[image][image]

<s>I've also added this to my [SE Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features).</s>

**Update:** I've had to remove this userscript from my SE Optional Features userscript due to reasons mentioned at that post. You can now install this userscript from [here](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/showAnswerCountSidebar.user.js).

Answer (score 2):

No, because I love votes more than answers, they often tell me better the usefulness or quality of the question I am about to click.

No, because I get used to see the votes there.

Hopefully, big

[image]

Comment: I am not talking about what you like or don't like lol. Votes do tell quality, but it doesn't add anything when there are no answers right? I also find good answers in hell lot of down-voted questions.

Comment: `No, because I love votes more than answers`  The OP is not asking about your likes and dislikes, Please read the [Help center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You have a nice rep but still don't know how to answer

Comment: @Bio I do know :P we're on meta, what are you talking about? It is built on likes and dislikes whining, polls :)

Comment: @nicael I am talking about your answer. Your personal opinion

Comment: @Bio Yes. Meta is opinions, I forget to note :D

Comment: @nicael `Yes. Meta is opinions` Yes downvoted opinions.:P

Comment: @Bio Nah, [upvoted opinions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) :D

Comment: Never seen so many "I" in an answer accompanied with oversized images  !

Comment: Isn't my tag @funny? And you forgot to add "before" ;)