# Please cool the color of the questions which have my favorite tags (beta theme)

Tags: feature-request, design, beta-sites

The colorscheme on beta sites is blueish and "cold", but this yellow color of the questions which contain your favourite tags dizzies me pretty much.

[image]

The earlier beta theme used light blue, which is apparently used by MSE now.

**Please revert to the old good light blue.**

Comment: People with blue perception deficiencies will not be able to see the light blue

Comment: I see it as pink...

Comment: ...on one of my screens... And yellow on the other. Grr, VGA and DVI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ummmm... No. That is totally [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as @Mooseman said. It had been *made* that way for a good amount of time already and seemingly no critics on this situation.

The yellow is great for not covering that text and for standing out just enough from the white to know that the question marked has a favorite tag used. There is no problem with the yellow and you really can't get dizzy from the yellow unless you have seen only yellow for the past hour. It seems to be personal here...

I agree with @Mooseman so hopefully: [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Comment: +1 - but use nicael's style!! http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251772/260841

Comment: Yes, like @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ said, use my style to disagree with my requests! :D I can't even see this tiny [tag:status-declined]!

Comment: @nicael You want to your use your own suggestion to deny your other suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Not only does this sound [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but it really isn't an issue. It doesn't degrade the UX; the same point gets across.

Comment: It doesn't match the color scheme at all. It should be a cold color, while its quite warm.

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to be useful. It would be more relevant if you said *why* you disagreed with the feature proposed.

Comment: @bjb have you tried it? Something doesn't appear to work properly? :P

Comment: upvoted this answer, for the reasons stated in the answer - it really is not an earth-shattering issue

Comment: Correct. @SabreTooth! It doesn't shatter the Earth! It shatters the Universe instead, sparing Earth...