# Where's The Name?

Tags: support, mobile-web, unicode

I was on the mobile webpage for Meta.SE (Google on Samsung Galaxy 2) and somehow, the user's name just disappeared: ([link to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252113/152859))

> [image]

Yet on my desktop, using Google Chrome, the user's name does show up:

> [image]

So where is the user's name and why doesn't it show up the mobile-web version?

Comment: Your mobile device OS does not support the fancy Unicode characters used by the user as display name. It's not Stack Exchange fault.

Comment: But my mobile device does!

Comment: Nope. [iPhone does](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DkTDi.png). Steps to solve the bug: upgrade to iPhone. ;)

Comment: lol - I know - but I can't find the font for Android! @ShadowWizard I know - it's my fault ;p

Comment: @ShadowWizard Surely you mean downgrade? :)

Comment: @Doorknob mehgrade :-)

Comment: Would be cool if the username was invisiable though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just how Android has displayed unknown characters for a *long* time, by just displaying an empty space instead of the usual empty box that we've come to know from most operating systems. There's absolutely nothing Stack Exchange can do about it.

However, the most recent releases of Android do fix this problem (at least the Lollipop update on my HTC One M8 fixed it) by displaying boxes with crosses through them:

> [image: Characters fixed!]

Comment: And latest Chrome can display it on Nexus 5 running on Lollipop 5.1 http://i.stack.imgur.com/pgflX.jpg so yeah, it really depends on the browser, fonts and device.